# Partition string based on delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

The string stored in nvarchar field like 'CA:No:1250.00000' and want to partition the string based on delimiter like 
column 1 should show CA (State) 
column 2 should show No (Recoverable Non-Recoverable) 
column 3 should show 1250.00000 (Tax rate)

I've tried below code but it won't work in all the cases. IF Recov sets to Yes

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(SDESC, 0, CHARINDEX(':', SDESC)) AS STATENAME,
    SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(SDESC, CHARINDEX(':', SDESC) + 1, LEN(SDESC)), 0, CHARINDEX(':', SUBSTRING(SDESC, CHARINDEX(':', SDESC) +
    1, LEN(SDESC)))) RECOV,
    SUBSTRING(SDESC, CHARINDEX(':', SDESC) + 4, LEN(SDESC)) AS REMANING
FROM
    LOOKUP
WHERE
    SLISTNAME = 'StateTax'
```

The expected result is 3 different columns based on delimiter : occurrence

Comment: can you post some sample data which is not working on your above mentioned query, with expected result.

Comment: 'CA:No:1250.00000'
'IL:Yes:0.004789'
'MN:Yes:0.001245'

Comment: got your point, posted my ans please check

Comment: If the first part is always two characters then you can simplify quite a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this. As your string format is same and there are always 2 `:` in your string. So we'll use `REVERSE` to get the last part of the string, since middle section is of variable length i,e; `3` for `YES` and `2` for `NO`.

```
declare @str nvarchar(max) = 'CA:YES:1250.00000'

SELECT
    SUBSTRING(@str, 0, CHARINDEX(':', @str)) AS STATENAME,
    SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@str, CHARINDEX(':', @str) + 1, LEN(@str)), 0, CHARINDEX(':', SUBSTRING(@str, CHARINDEX(':', @str) +
    1, LEN(@str)))) RECOV,
    REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@str), 0, CHARINDEX(':', REVERSE(@str)))  ) AS REMANING
```

Result:-

```
STATENAME   RECOV   REMAINING
--------------------------------
CA           YES    1250.00000



For I/p 'IL:Yes:0.004789'

STATENAME   RECOV   REMAINING
--------------------------------
IL           Yes    0.004789
```

Answer (score 1):

Since first 2 parts of the string are relatively static, you could do:

```
select
left(sdesc,2) col1,
replace(substring(sdesc,4,3),':','') col2,
replace(stuff(sdesc, 1,6, ''),':','') col3
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select substring(SDESC, 1, charindex(":", SDESC) - 1) --should give you the state,
select substring(SDESC, 4, charindex(":", SDESC) - 1) --should give you the NO, etc.
select right(SDESC, charindex(":", reverse(SDESC)) - 1) --should give you the rest.
```